# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I'm trying to decompose a crash on my Android app from a device with the following specs:

```
Device
PAP3400DUO 1
Manufacturer — Android version Android 4.2 RAM (MB) — Screen size 480 × 800 Screen density (dpi) 240 OpenGL ES version 2.0 Native platform armeabi-v7a
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
    at com.yitter.android.activity.EditProfileActivity.lambda$setSubmitProfileChangesClickListener$46(EditProfileActivity.java:120)
    at com.yitter.android.activity.EditProfileActivity.access$lambda$1(EditProfileActivity.java)
    at com.yitter.android.activity.EditProfileActivity$$Lambda$2.onClick(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is it really pointing me to line 120? The code there shows this approximately:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("profilePicture.png", image);
            user1.put("profilePicture", file);
```

What could the problem possibly be? I researched the ClassCastException thrown but I can't seem to put the two together. What does `drawable.ColorDrawable` have to do with my bitmap here?

**Edit:**

```
<ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
                        android:layout_width="87dp"
                        android:layout_height="87dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc_profile_picture"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Apparently, `imageView` does not contain a `BitmapDrawable`, but rather a `ColorDrawable`, in the situation where this exception occurs. You need to examine all of the different places that you are populating this `ImageView`. Or, better yet, rather than try to yank a drawable back out of an `ImageView`, get the image from your model objects or whatever data source you are using to populate the `ImageView` in the first place.

Comment: It would be better to fetch the object right then and there, but I've tracked down the issue: ``android:src="@android:color/transparent"``. That older Android device doesn't seem to like this very much in the ImageView for the profile picture. I've removed this line and the problem is now gone for those devices.

Comment: `VectorDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`